# Is there a 'requires' replacement for 'void_t'?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

`void_t` is a nice hack to detect compilability of certain expressions, but I wonder if there is some way to do that check with `requires` (or requires requires  ) since I really do not like `void_t` from the readability perspective.

For example, for a certain type I want to check if some expression is fine (i.e. compilable) or not, including negations.

Ideally I would wish that this works, but it does not, probably since lambdas are not templated...

```
#include <unordered_set>


int main() {
    auto a = []() requires requires(int x) {x<x;} {};
    auto b = []() requires !requires(std::unordered_set<int> x) {x<x;} {};
}
```

If this use seems weird, my real motivation is to check that something does not compile, for example that my nontemplated type does not have `operator<` or that it is not constructible from `int` or...

P.S.: I know `boost::hana` has [a way to do this](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/example/type/is_valid.cpp), I am looking for vanilla C++20 solution.

Comment: How does `void_t` solve the problem here, exactly? No template means no sfinae, and hard errors regardless of what you use.

Comment: Modern compilers don't seem to allow `requires` constraints outside of templates, but otherwise this is legal, if you parenthesize the negation. I don't see how this differs from the normal use of `requires`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your snippet is about constraining a non-template lambda, but your prose is about checking behaviour of some type. Which is it?

Comment: *For example for a certain type I want to check if some expression is fine or not* Can't you just write a concept to do that?

Comment: @NathanOliver not a fan of writing concepts for a simple problems, but then again it is just 1 line extra, will try.

Comment: @NathanOliver it worked, https://godbolt.org/z/c66Pojzo7 still not a fan of having to write concept for simple cases, but it is not too bad. You can write this as an answer and I will accept

Comment: @PasserBy lambda is irrelevant in itself, I just needed somwhere to stick requires... also

Comment: @NathanOliver I managed to get the stuff to compile without concept, but I had to use polymorphic lambda, so it looks terrible https://godbolt.org/z/dK7vfWYjG

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl If you are just trying to keep how much code you have to write down, you should look into using a macro to stamp out all the boiler plate for you.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: `if constexpr(requires {int{} < int{};}) { return true; } else { return false; }` can simply be `return requires {int{} < int{};};`.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, did not know c++ is nice enough to allow that, you can add that answer if you want., will upvote

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It doesn't directly solve the OP case. As `static_assert(false);`, `requires (std::unordered_set<int> x) {x<x;}` make the program ill-formed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my real motivation is to check that something does not compile, for example that my nontemplated type does not have `operator <`

This is possible with concepts, perhaps I am misunderstanding?

```
template<class T>
concept has_less_than = requires(const T& x, const T& y)
{
   {x < y} -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

struct Has_Less
{
    bool operator<(const Has_Less& other) const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

struct Nope{};

int main()
{
    static_assert(has_less_than<Has_Less>);
    static_assert(!has_less_than<Nope>);
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qrY8Wes6G)

Comment: I prefered to avoid writing concept, but it seems impossible since requires will error out if you put types that are not template arguments inside requires... you can see my last comment to question with link to https://godbolt.org/z/dK7vfWYjG for a ugly working solution that must use polymorphic lambda

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Concepts are unrelated, you can rewrite this answer without them. Your issue was that the `requires`-*constraints* can't appear outside of templates (but `requires`-expressions can).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that is certainly obvious and easy to remember, like all things C++ :) thank you for clarification

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I mean, it should be somewhat obvious in hindsight. You can't disable non-template things with the conventional SFINAE, so `requires`(-constraint) doesn't allow that as well. (Though it does allow disabling non-template members of templates, unlike SFINAE.) But `requires`-expression (which is a thing that returns a boolean based on whether the braced SFINAE-condition is satisfied) works everywhere, because why not.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer of @AndyG is perfectly fine, I would like to make an addition.
You can make an ad-hoc concept as well, like you can see in the next example program (includes are missing):

```
void func( auto v )
{
    // unnamed concept in constexpr if-branch!
    if constexpr( requires { { v < v }->std::same_as<bool>; } ) {
        // use operator
        puts( "HAVE operator <" );
    } else {
        // cannot use operator
        puts( "no operator <" );
    }
}

struct X {};

int main()
{
    func( 2 );
    func( X{} );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Tested with VisualStudio 2022 (17.3.5) in C++20 mode.

This technique is named "Design by introspection". I also recently wrote a short blog post to this (can be found in my profile).